# Qual a diferença entre Angular 2 e Angular 4?

Tags: angular

Gostaria de saber de uma forma simplificada, qual as diferenças entre Angular 2 e Angular 4? E se possível, indicações sobre materiais de estudo das duas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existem grande tipo de diferenças apenas correções e melhorias, na verdade o Angular 4 é o Angular 2.

A primeira versão do framework era **AngularJS** escrita em Javascript. depois apareceu **Angular** sem o JS, é a nova versão do framework, escrita em Typescript. Aqui mudaram a forma de atribuição de versão passando a (2.x, 3.x, 4.x, por adiante). Não significa que exista falta de compatibilidade com a versão anterior.

> Mais informações acerca [aqui](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) do CHANGELOG do Angular.

Se pretende aprofundar e estudar sem dúvida o google é um excelente motor de busca e vai conseguir encontrar muita informação de por onde começar, no entanto deixo aqui um [exemplo](https://tableless.com.br/comecando-com-o-angular-material%E2%80%8A-parte-1/), que já o vai ajudar um pouco.

Answer (score -1):

O Angular 4 é uma atualização do Angular 2 (O correto é falar apenas Angular).

A grande diferença que existe é entre o "Angular 1" e o "Angular 2", que na verdade devem ser chamados de "Angular JS" e "Angular".